# Ubuntu 14.04 Multiple Display Intel Gen 3

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors

I'm a newbie at this and I am messing around with dual booting into Ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to get my monitors to be recognised by Ubuntu but I have been unsuccessful...

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 900, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1600x900       60.0*+   40.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I am using a diamond docking station that is most likely the culprit, but I wanted to ask the community to see if they have  any ideas for me to try.

Thanks!